# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies - problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error and i really can t solve it:

```
src/api/ConnectApi.js
  Line 25:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'apiurl', 'dataState', and 'fetch'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setDataState(d => ...)' if you only need 'dataState' in the 'setDataState' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Here's what i have in ConnectApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useCollectData = (url) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const [fetch, setFetching] = useState({isFetching: false})
        const [dataState, setDataState] = useState({data: []});
        const [apiurl] = useState(url);

                const fetchDataFromApi = async () => {

                    try{
                        setFetching({isFetching: true})
                        const response = await axios.get(apiurl)
                        setDataState({...dataState, data: response.data});
                    }
                    catch (error){
                        setFetching({...fetch, isFetching: true})
                    }
                };
                fetchDataFromApi();
                // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    },[]);
    return [dataState]
};

export default useCollectData
```

I tried to add apiurl, dataState and fetch to the dependencies array but it won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling useState inside useEffect, which breaks hooks rules.
React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useCollectData = (url) => {
    const [fetch, setFetching] = useState({isFetching: false})
    const [dataState, setDataState] = useState({data: []});
    const [apiurl] = useState(url);
    useEffect(() => {
                const fetchDataFromApi = async () => {

                    try{
                        setFetching({isFetching: true})
                        const response = await axios.get(apiurl)
                        setDataState({...dataState, data: response.data});
                    }
                    catch (error){
                        setFetching({...fetch, isFetching: true})
                    }
                };
                fetchDataFromApi();
                // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    },[]);
    return [dataState]
};

export default useCollectData
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now my problem is solved :D

Answer (score 0):

`useState` should be declared outside `useEffect`.

```js
const [fetch, setFetching] = useState({isFetching: false})
const [dataState, setDataState] = useState({data: []});
const [apiurl] = useState(url);
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchDataFromApi = async () => {

    try{
      setFetching({isFetching: true})
      const response = await axios.get(apiurl)
      setDataState({...dataState, data: response.data});
    }
    catch (error){
      setFetching({...fetch, isFetching: true})
    }
  };
  fetchDataFromApi();
  eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
},[]);
```